# What is the running time of the zigzag traversal in a matrix?

Tags: performance

What is the average running time of the following traversal?

We are traversing from bottom left to top right. That's our first diagonal. Then randomly picking one (purple) and creating another diagonal, but this time to cover all elements on that diagonal from its top left to its bottom right. Then we are randomly picking another element and creating another diagonal. .... until we can't create a diagonal from the current node. See below where yellow is unvisited and green is visited. Purple is the randomly picked node in that diagonal to determine the next diagonal.

[image]

We start with diagonal 1 and mark all nodes there green. We randomly pick one node (purple) and move to diagonal 2 and to 3.. until we stop at diagonal 5 because all the nodes are already visited and we can't create the diagonal 5, so we stop.

Given that the matrix is NxN, best case running time is `O(N)` and worst case is `O(N^2)`, but the average I think is better than the worst case, because we don't really hit the worst case that often. What is the average or amortized running time of this algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be too simple, but in case of an n x n matrix there's  (2n-1) diagonals from lower left to upper right and again (2n-1) diagonals from lower right to upper left. so it's 2 x (2n-1) = 4n-2 diagonals on overall. As you end you algorithm when you pick a purple point with existing diagonals, the absolute worst case is you always select an "unused" diagonal. So it would be a new diagonal each time - which is 4n-2 picks. But even this is O(n).

If you're not referring to "purple picks" but to "try coloring a point on the picked diagonal" it's again a factor of 2 (as a point can only be coloured twice as every third pick would imply the condition for ending the algo would be reached). This also is O(n)

Answer (score 1):

**O(n^2).**

**Worst case**: 4n-2 diagonal checks.

**Average case**: O(n) diagonal checks as well.

**Each diagonal check**: O(n).

**Total**: O(n^2).